# Where is there posted dampening coefficients for viscous dampers?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Depending on the size of the viscous dampener the coefficient will change, however i am trying to model a "physical" system with calculating everything out, so that way i can test failure before it happens. Although I've read that somewhere they have these posted.